# Are most sitcoms racially segregated?

Tags: the-big-bang-theory

Just finished watching the 12 seasons of The Big Bang Theory, 12 seasons, 279 episodes roughly 5580 minutes if you average 20 minutes per episode. Yet in that 5580 minutes there is less than (I'm guessing) 10 minutes of black people being on screen. I can only think of:

- The black receptionist in S1E1
- The black receptionist at the hospital when Howard robotic arm get stuck on his genitalia
- Glenn (Bernadette's former boyfriend)
- Janine Davis (HR lady at the University)
- Neil DeGrasse Tyson
- Kareem Abdul-Jabbar

**So that's effectively no black people in a sitcom that lasted more than 10 years.**

The same could be said of Friends and Seinfeld, but **equally the same in reverse could be said about the Cosby Show,Living Single or the Fresh Prince of Bel-Air**.

Whilst it could be said that these are the genuine viewpoints of the characters, I don't understand why more of a big deal is not made about this.

**Is there a history of Sitcoms being racially segregated and is this legal?**

Comment: You observations are definitely not wrong, sitcoms often have a target audience.  There are interesting articles you can find like this from the Washington Post https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/politics/1994/11/29/a-television-trend-audiences-in-black-and-white/68851536-e46b-4071-a1d1-9a510a59077e/

Comment: As far as I know racists describes the opinions of racial hostility that racist people feel.  Since a sitcom is not a person a sitcom can not be racist.  A sitcom could show the racist attitudes of racists creators.  I think that it would have been more accurate for you to ask if the sitcoms you mentioned were "racially segregated" or "racially based" or "racially biased" or something.  See TV Tropes like "Humans are White", "Minority Show Ghetto", etc.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Good point, I have changed the title.

Comment: There have been numerous articles on Friends being ridiculously white, even during its run. Hell, the character Charlie Wheeler was basically introduced as a response to such criticism. This is far from a recent insight, despite what many people think.

Comment: I'd like to point out that Raj has been a major cast member since the beginning. He's not Caucasian. (Also, LeVar Burton had a recurring role, as I recall.)

Comment: @BrettFromLA I'd totally forgotten about LeVar Burton, but to be honest he's in the same boat as Neil DeGrasse Tyson he appeared so little in comparison to the overall show.

Comment: One of your questions is, is it "legal to do this" (not have many black people on a show)? Of course it's legal. There is no law that says you have to have black, Asian, Indian, etc., people on any show or movie. Would "My Dinner with Andre" have been better if a black person was shoehorned in because it didn't feature one? *Not everything needs to be political.*

Comment: @MeatTrademark Even though it is a show it is still also a workplace, as such it would be of concern if over 10 years not a single black person was hired.

Comment: @Naz, do you have any evidence to support your claim that in 10 years on the air there was never a black editor, script writer, camera operator. sound mixer, etc. associated with this show?

Comment: @BrettFromLA mentions "Raj … not Caucasian".  Technically, according to the original racial definitions, Indians *are* Caucasian (same physical features, but darker skin).

Comment: @krb I am referring to the actors.

Comment: @Naz good for you, but the actors are not the only employees in that workplace

Comment: @krb Who exactly is disputing that?

Comment: Personally, if I was an employer, I would look for the most qualified person for any role. Iin front or behind the camera. If a white guy is a better cinematographer, should I hire [a minority] even if they aren't as good at their profession? It sucks that the system works the way it does and that black people do not have enough input. Things are getting better. Granted, it's very slow.

Comment: @MeatTrademark That's fine, but lets say the owner of company A is white and all the employees in his company are white, and lets say the owner of company B is black and all her employees are black that would look a bit suspicious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UCLA published [a study](https://socialsciences.ucla.edu/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/UCLA-Hollywood-Diversity-Report-2018-2-27-18.pdf) that covered racial diversity on TV:

> Despite quite a bit of progress for [racial minorities] since the previous report, they remained underrepresented on every front in 2015-16:
>
> - 2 to 1 among broadcast scripted leads (18.7 percent)
> - Nearly 2 to 1 among cable scripted leads (20.2 percent)
> - Nearly 2 to 1 among broadcast reality and other leads (26.6 percent)
> - Nearly 2 to 1 among leads for cable reality and other leads (20.9 percent) [...]
> - Greater than 5 to 1 among the creators of broadcast scripted shows (7.1 percent)
> - Greater than 5 to 1 among the creators of cable scripted shows (7.3 percent)

This covers all people of color, not just black people. Additionally I found the article [Black representation in film and TV: The challenges and impact of increasing diversity](https://www.mckinsey.com/featured-insights/diversity-and-inclusion/black-representation-in-film-and-tv-the-challenges-and-impact-of-increasing-diversity#) which gives the numbers for black people specifically, which even notes:

> The prominence of certain films and TV series with Black leads obscures the fact that Black actors are still underrepresented on-screen. While their overall representation among film casts is broadly in line with the Black share of the US population (13.4 percent), Black actors play only 11 percent of leading film roles and are often funneled to race-related projects, which typically receive lower investment in both production and promotion.

TBBT, as far as I can tell from IMDb, seems to have even less diversity in actors than your average show. See:

- [List of cast](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0898266/fullcredits/cast?ref_=m_tt_cl_sc). Janine Davis seems to be the black character who appears in the most episodes
- [Producers](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0898266/fullcredits/producer?ref_=m_ttfc_4). These are the people who make the important decisions for the show. I was not able to look through the entire list (and there are several other lists of important people) but I saw one black producer (and another Japanese-American one).

Neither of these really makes a good case for  TBBT's diversity.

The other aspect that's worth considering, though too subjective to be covered by statistics, is the type of roles: How diverse are the roles that these actors are in (as opposed to just stereotypical ones)? Are jokes being made with regard to their race? With TBBT:

- In a show about nerds, how many characters were black nerds? How many black characters were in a [STEM career](https://undark.org/2020/09/11/after-years-of-gains-black-stem-representation-is-falling-why/)? (I cannot remember there being any such characters, other than the occasional celebrity like Neil DeGrasse Tyson.)
- Think about [Janine Davis](https://bigbangtheory.fandom.com/wiki/Janine_Davis) (from the university HR). Race (and gender) played a big role in many of her appearances. But was it good representation? Maybe not, as Sheldon was racist and sexist towards her, but in the end there were no real consequences for his behavior.
- More broadly, think about Raj. The fact that one of the main characters isn't white is a step in the right direction, but again it's necessary to look at how he's portrayed. Is it the type of portrayal that makes a viewer proud to be Indian, like Raj? Or does it use him being Indian, an "other", as the joke? There are plenty of articles written by people who [find Raj to be a problematic character](https://librarypartnerspress.pressbooks.pub/studentessaysculturesitcomv1/chapter/regressive-yet-crucial-controversies-in-the-big-bang-theory/) (with race being only one facet).